# getBoundingClientRect is reading a null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the error shown in the title, and don't know why. Basically I want to get back in the console log a set a values including the height of the links.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Why is that. Does it come from the useRef(null) assigned on the linksRef variable?
Here is the component!
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FaBars, FaTwitter } from 'react-icons/fa'
import { links, social } from './data'
import logo from './logo.svg'
 
const Navbar = () => {
  const [showLinks, setShowLinks] = useState(false)
  const linksContainerRef = useRef(null)
  const linksRef = useRef(null)
 
  useEffect(() => {
    // We' ll use the height of the links to
    // adjust the height of the list container
    const linkHeight = linksRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
  }, [showLinks])
  return (
    <nav>
      <div className='nav-center'>
        <div className='nav-header'>
          <img src={logo} alt='logo' />
          <button
            className='nav-toggle'
            onClick={() => {
              setShowLinks(!showLinks)
            }}
          >
            <FaBars />
          </button>
        </div>
        {showLinks && (
          <div
            className='links-container'
            ref={linksContainerRef}
            // className={`${
            //   showLinks ? 'links-container show-container' : 'links-container'
            // }`}
          >
            <ul className='links' ref={linksRef}>
              {links.map((link) => {
                const { id, url, text } = link
                return (
                  <li key={id}>
                    <a href={url}>{text}</a>
                  </li>
                )
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
        )}
        <ul className='social-icons'>
          {social.map((socialIcon) => {
            const { id, url, icon } = socialIcon
            return (
              <li key={id}>
                <a href={url}>{icon}</a>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}
 
export default Navbar
```

Thanks,
Theo.

Comment: `linksRef` is initially setup as a `null`. And it's only shown when `showLinks` toggled, and `showLinks` initial value is also `false`. If you get what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, do a not null check before accessing anything on a `ref.current`.